# How to run test in subdirectories that are sub projects

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

This is my structure

```
MyApp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── config
│   ├── controller
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── config
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── configurationtest.cpp
    │   └── main.cpp
    ├── controller
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── controllertest.cpp
        └── main.cpp
```

When I want to execute my tests I have to select ControllerTests and Run it. Same thing for ConfigurationTest, individually.

I would like to add something in the top-level CMakeLists.txt of Tests to be able to run all tests in subdirectories.
This is my top-level tests CMakeLists.txt

```
project(MyAppTests)

include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories($ENV{GMOCK_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(config)
add_subdirectory(controller)
```

Each subdirectories have a main.cpp, and `add_executable`. In the configuration CMakeLists.txt there is that line :

```
add_test(NAME ConfigurationTests COMMAND ConfigurationTests)
```

Comment: I'm curious if you know about `enable_testing()`, `add_test()` and `ctest.exe` (see e.g. [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest))?

Comment: We have an option that activated all of that in the root of the project.

Answer (score 1):

CMake should have automatically generated a target `RUN_TESTS` that lunch all the tests defined in your project.

If it is not here, you may have forgotten to set [`BUILD_TESTING`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_test.html) option to `ON` :

> CMake will generate tests only if the enable_testing() command has been invoked. The **CTest module invokes the command automatically** when the **BUILD_TESTING** option is **ON**.

Comment: Except that `BUILD_TESTING` is `ON` by default, according to : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/CTest.html

Answer (score 1):

Using [ctest](/questions/tagged/ctest) executable does gives you some more flexibility over using the predefined `RUN_TESTS` target. I'm using the following call - executed inside my binary output directory - to run all my tests:

```
ctest.exe -C Debug -j 16 --no-compress-output -T Test --timeout 600
```

I do want

- to run the `Debug` configuration of the tests
- to run upto `16` tests in parallel
- to have `no-compress-output` because I prefer this formatting
- to `Test` the software by loading `CTestTestfile.cmake` and execute the defined tests

  - Also the output and result of each test is recorded (see `Testing\...\Test.xml` which e.g. can be evaluated by Jenkins [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin))
- to timeout tests after `600` seconds

Comment: This worked for me. I have my tests in an executable target in a subdirectory of the main CMakeLists.txt. Running ctest.exe, in the binary output directory of the subdirectory's target, allows ctest to find and execute all of its tests. Thx!